# React Stripe Heroku - checkout payment not working anymore after deployment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement stripe to my small e-commerce website developed in reactjs. To do so I've used the checkout component.

It works perfectly when i'm on localhost, but after i deploy the backend with heroku I receive this error message :
[image]

Apparently i didn't provide the API key but I feel like I did... I don't understand ...
Anyone ?

On the front end :

```
// Linking with the back end
  const makePayment = (token) => {
    const body = {
      token: token,
      product: product,
    };
    const headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    };
    return fetch(`https://serotonineneshop.herokuapp.com/payment`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("RESPONSE : ", response);
        const { status } = response;
        console.log("STATUS : ", status);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
```

on the back-end :

```
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY)
app.post("/payment", (req, res) => {
  const {
    product,
    token
  } = req.body;
  const idempotencyKey = uuidv4()
  return stripe.customers.create({
    email: token.email,
    source: token.id
  }).then(customer => {
    stripe.charges.create({
        amount: product.price * 100,
        currency: "eur",
        customer: customer.id,
        receipt_email: token.email,
        description: `purchase of ${product.name}`,
        shipping: {
          name: token.card.name,
          phone: token.card.phone,
          address: {
            country: token.card.address_country,
            postAddress: token.card.address,
            zipCode: token.card.zipCode
          }
        }
      }, {
        idempotencyKey
      })
      .then(result = res.status(202).json(result))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  })
});
```

Comment: Have you set STRIPE_SECRET_KEY in your [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)?

Comment: I had NOT ! and it was absolutely the issue here ! Thank you so much 